# Get current time, on commit, with oracle database

Tags: oracle, plsql

When inserting a row I want to set a column, equal to the current time on commit.

If I use default value `sysdate` on the column, it uses the current time at insert (which could be significantly different to commit time).  If I use an on insert trigger, it again uses the time at the insert - not the actual commit.

Are there any possible solutions to get current time on commit with oracle ?

Comment: Cross post: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139020/get-current-time-on-commit-with-oracle-database

Comment: please read policy for cross posting, delete it here and see [there](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139020/get-current-time-on-commit-with-oracle-database?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: I would try to see what timestamp gets recorded with AUDIT OBJECT for successful insert.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in the first place? You are probably trying to solve a different problem. Capturing the timestamp of `commit` may not be the only solution, or (very likely) even the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

There are options.  They may be rather more heavyweight than you were hoping for, though.

You could create a fast-refreshable materialized view that refreshes on commit and put a trigger on that materialized view that would fire when the row commits.  That would mean, though, that you'd need a materialized view log on the base table so your insert would incur the overhead of writing to the table and the log plus you'd incur the cost of the materialized view refresh when you committed.  If you ever had to do a full refresh of the materialized view, you'd need to make sure to turn off the trigger as well.  That's quite a few moving pieces that will add complexity to your system.

Depending on the Oracle version, you might be able to enable Flashback Data Archive (also known as Total Recall) which would record the SCN and timestamp of when each version of data was committed.  The downside there is that you'd then have a potentially large history table that is likely tracking a bunch of information that you don't care about.